# SQLalchemy attribute error when dynamically creating both table and columns names when using string variables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having an issue where I need to create a new tables and a specific columns because I need to do SELECT INTO from a regular data table into a mapping table. The table names and two columns names are dynamic due to the nature of the data that I'm working with in the database.

I tried using an example in [Use variable column headings in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367868/use-variable-column-headings-in-sqlalchemy), but I'm still getting errors being raised. Here's the basic code:

```
                RecIndex = # some string key value that changes
                tableData = "Data-" + str(i)
                tableName = f'Mapping{idx}'
                colName = f'Voltage{i}-V{idx}'

                col_list = ['Reading', 'Date', colName]
                t_list = {TableData: [RecIndex, colName], tableName: [RecIndex, colName]}
                table_list = []

                for t_name, col_name in t_list.items():
                    t = Table(
                        t_name, metadata,
                        Column('Reading', Integer),
                        Column('Date', Date),
                        *[Column(name, Integer) for name in col_name]
                    )

                    table_list.append(t)

                t1 = table_list[0]      # Mapping table
                t2 = table_list[1]      # Data table

                sel = t1.insert().from_select(col_list, t2.select().where(t2.c.colName > 0))  # FAILS HERE
```

However, when I try to build the sel variable, it fails and I get this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 1201, in **getattr**
> return self._index[key]

> KeyError: 'colName'

> sel = t1.insert().from_select(col_list, t2.select().where(t2.c.colName > 0))

> File "C:\Python\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 1203, in **getattr**
> util.raise_(AttributeError(key), replace_context=err)

> File "C:\Python\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
> raise exception

> AttributeError: colName

Anyone have any idea on why it isn't working? I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code you are referencing the column by the name of the variable, `colName` instead of the contents of the variable, ie. `"Voltage0-V2"`.  Try something like this:

```py
sel = t1.insert().from_select(col_list, t2.select().where(getattr(t2.c, colName) > 0))
```

This is just the built-in getattr:
[getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

I think `dict` style lookups are also supported ie. `t2.c[colName]`, so this might work too:

```py
sel = t1.insert().from_select(col_list, t2.select().where(t2.c[colName] > 0))
```

Comment: Both worked and did the trick. Thanks dude!